# Why isn't a member of type Option[String] being serialized?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, option-type, play-json

I have a dummy class `Foo` which has three members:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Foo(id: String, fooType: FooType, nextId: Option[String])

object Foo {
  implicit val fooReads = Json.reads[Foo]
  implicit val fooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

where `FooType` is defined as

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class FooType(a: String, b: String)

object FooType {
  implicit val fooTypeReads = Json.reads[FooType]
  implicit val fooTypeFormat = Json.format[FooType]
}
```

I find some interesting behavior when serializing a `Foo` object. If I serialize a `Foo` to JSON, parse the JSONified Foo, I find that all the members are parsed correctly:

```
val id = "id"
val fooType = FooType("a", "b")
val nextId = None

val foo = Foo(id, fooType, nextId)
val jsonFoo = Json.toJson(foo)
val parsedFoo = Json.parse(jsonFoo.toString).as[Foo]

assert(parsedFoo == foo)
assert(parsedFoo.id == id)
assert(parsedFoo.fooType == fooType)
assert(parsedFoo.nextId.isEmpty)
```

This is good, because that's what I expect.

However, in my next test, I find that the `nextId` field is *not* serializable at all:

```
val id = "id"
val fooType = FooType("a", "b")
val nextId = None

val foo = Foo(id, fooType, nextId)
val jsonFoo = Json.toJson(foo)

assert((jsonFoo \ "id").as[String] == id)
assert((jsonFoo \ "fooType").as[FooType] == fooType)
assert((jsonFoo \ "nextId").as[Option[String]].isEmpty)
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Error:(38, 35) No Json deserializer found for type Option[String]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
    assert((jsonFoo \ "nextId").as[Option[String]].isEmpty)

Error:(38, 35) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit fjs: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[String]])Option[String].
Unspecified value parameter fjs.
    assert((jsonFoo \ "nextId").as[Option[String]].isEmpty)
```

Similarly, I find that when I print the JSON object dumped by `Json.toJson(foo)`, the `nextId` field is missing from the JSON object:

```
println(Json.prettyPrint(jsonFoo))

{
  "id" : "id",
  "fooType" : {
    "a" : "a",
    "b" : "b"
  }
}
```

I can, however, parse the `nextId` field with `toOption`; i.e.,

```
assert((jsonFoo \ "nextId").toOption.isEmpty)
```

How can my object be correctly parsed from JSON if one of its members isn't deserializable natively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nextId` field is serializable, otherwise, you wouldn't have been able to write a `Foo` to JSON at all.

```
jsonFoo: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":"id","fooType":{"a":"a","b":"b"}}
```

The problem you're having is that there are no `Reads` for `Option[A]`. Options are handled specially by Play JSON. When using JSON combinators, we use `readNullable[A]` and `writeNullable[A]` instead of `read[Option[A]]` and `write[Option[A]]`. Likewise, when using methods to pull individual fields from a `JsValue`, calling `as` will not work because it requires an implicit `Reads[A]` for the type you give it (in this case a `Reads[Option[String]]`, which does not exist).

Instead, you need to use `asOpt`, which will correctly handle the `Option` underneath:

```
scala> (jsonFoo \ "nextId").asOpt[String]
res1: Option[String] = None
```

`nextId` doesn't appear in the printed JSON because the value you are serializing is `None`. This is what is expected to happen. Since the value is optional, it gets omitted from the JSON (it's just `undefined` in JavaScript). If it has a value, it will appear:

```
scala> Json.toJson(Foo("id", FooType("a", "b"), Option("abcdef")))
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":"id","fooType":{"a":"a","b":"b"},"nextId":"abcdef"}
```

If something wasn't serializable with Play JSON, it simply wouldn't compile.

Comment: Interesting. I might expect `None` to be serialized to `null` or a `JsNull` object in Play, but I'm now seeing that I'd have to define a custom writer for that. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: It only goes one way. A missing field or `null` in JSON will get mapped to an `Option`, but an `Option` can only be mapped to one of the two going the other way. The designers chose omitting the field as the more sensible thing to do.

Comment: Makes sense. So long as it can be parsed correctly, that's fine -- that's the crux.